# loading content into a div from data within a href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so I am using Jquery to try and get a href link with a data variable that represents a div to load in an class called tile-are-main... it doesn't seem to be working though...

```
<script type="text/javascript">


$(function(){
    $(".submenu-who.nav-container a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('href') + ' #' + $(this).attr('data-target');
        $('.tile-area-main').load(url);
    });
});
</script>
```

this is the menu with the href in it ...

```
<body class="metro">

   <div class="submenu-who">

  <header class='masthead'>
  <div class='brand-container'>
    <a href='#'>
      <span class='brand-initials'>Who Are Musability?</span>
      <span><i class="fa fa-briefcase brand-initials-icon"></i></span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <div class='nav-container'>
      <div>
      <a class='slide' href='#' data-target='mission'>
          <span class='element'>Mission and Values</span>
         </a>
      </div>
```

it is the a href with the data'mission' bit that refers to a div of text that i want into tile-area-main.. to keep it simple.

**I think that I am missing out the classes between submenu-who and the a so in theory if i just add them all in with a space between each one that should work ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to add a space in between. The space is basically meant for all the children inside it, while no space between two classes is used when both the classes are applied to same element.

```
$(".submenu-who .nav-container a").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).attr('href') + ' #' + $(this).attr('data-target');
            $('.tile-area-main').load(url);
        });
```

Comment: have you changed your href='#' to a valid href ?

Comment: yes but this is the problem because the submenu is loaded into my index.html page ... if i put the actual href into it when i click it tries to go to the entire page and not the data tag

Comment: can u post a fiddle link ??

Comment: i was waiting for that ... i will try but there are way too many dependencies and also i am simulating going from different pages so jsfiddle probably wont suffice tbh

Comment: can we take this conversation to chat so i can post you some code

Comment: i think it would be helpful to exaplain in point form perhaps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79167/discussion-between-havingagoatit-and-dsaket).